# how many different names of Karna are mentioned in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, name, karna

I listen total 10 or 13 names are there but not knowing the names. I listen one or two like Radheya,Vashusena. So I want to know how many different names of Karna are mentioned in Mahabharata? Is there any story for each of them?

Answer (score 3):

- **Vasusena**: born with wealth. Because he was born with a natural armour and ear-rings. -[The Mahabharata, Book 1: Adi Parva: Sambhava Parva: Section CXI](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01112.htm) [The Mahabharata, Book 3: Vana Parva: Pativrata-mahatmya Parva: Section CCCVII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03307.htm)
- **Vrisha**: great splendour and immeasurable prowess. -[The Mahabharata, Book 3: Vana Parva: Pativrata-mahatmya Parva: Section CCCVII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03307.htm)
- **Karna**:
  the cutter or peeler of his own cover. Because he cut off his natural armour and gave it to Indra. -[The Mahabharata, Book 1: Adi Parva: Sambhava Parva: Section CXI](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01112.htm)
- **Vaikartana**: the son of Vikartana (Surya) - [The Mahabharata, Book 1: Adi Parva: Swayamvara Parva: Section CLXLII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01193.htm)
  [because Karna, cutting off his (natural) armour and his brilliant car-rings, gave them unto Sakra (indra), it is for that he came to be called Vaikartana. -[The Mahabharata, Book 7: Drona Parva: Ghatotkacha-badha Parva: Section CLXXX](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07177.htm)]
- **Radheya**: Radha's son -[The Mahabharata, Book 2: Sabha Parva: Sisupala-badha Parva: Section XLVII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02047.htm) & [The Mahabharata, Book 1: Adi Parva: Swayamvara Parva: Section CLXLII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01193.htm)
- **Suta's son**- [The Mahabharata, Book 6: Bhishma Parva: Bhagavat-Gita Parva: Section XCVIII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06098.htm) ==> Souta/Sutaputra
- **Adhiratha's son**:[The Mahabharata, Book 7: Drona Parva: Dronabhisheka Parva: Section XXX](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07030.htm) ==>Adhirathi
- **king of Anga**: [The Mahabharata, Book 1: Adi Parva: Sambhava Parva: Section CXXXVIII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01139.htm) ==>Angaraja
- **Surya's son**: [The Mahabharata, Book 8: Karna Parva: Section 90](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08090.htm) ==>Suryaputra

---

Karna had a bow named Vijaya ([The Mahabharata, Book 8: Karna Parva: Section 31](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08031.htm)) ==> Vijayadhari.

Karna was son of Kunti ==> Kaunteya

Karna was disciple of Parashurama ==> Parashuramashishya

Karna was of charitable nature ==> Danavira/Danashura

Answer (score 2):

**1**. **Vasusena** :
This is Karna’s original name given to him by his foster parents Adhiratha and his wife Radha.Vasusena means someone who is born with wealth i.e. natural armor (Kavach) and hear rings (Kundal).

**2. Radheya**: 
The popular name of Karna (Son of Kunti). Karna was never aware of the fact that he is the biological son of Kunti. Until Lord Krishna revealed the truth of his identity before the Kurukshetra war.
It is said, on his deathbed, he refused to be called the son of Kunti and wished to be remembered as the son of Radha.

**3.Vaikartana**: He got this name, as he carved his own kavach from his chest along with his kundal to offer to Indra, Brahmin in disguise.Though Karna aware of the fact, he gave his Kavach and Kundal to Indra.

**4.Angaraj**: 
Dronacharya arranged archery tournament in Hasthinapuram. Karna went to participate in that tournament against Arjuna. But he was not allowed into the tournament because the tournament is only for kings. Duryodhana wanting to see Arjuna’s defeat. He gave the part of his kingdom, Anga to Karna and made him king for Anga. Since then Karna named as Angaraj.

This gesture of Duryodhana was never forgotten by Angaraj and he remained loyal to him until his death.

**5.Sutaputra**:
The name 'Sutaputra' simply means "son of a charioteer", as his foster father Adhiratha was a charioteer. Karna was frequently addressed as Sutaoutra to insult him