# Why is it called Karna with such a name instead of Vasushena in Ranbhoomi?

Tags: mahabharata, name, karna

This is something that intrigues me, since according to Vaishampayana, Karna was called "Vaikartana Karna" after donating his armor to Indra (which happens in Vana Parva) but in Ranbhoomi (battle field) he is called Karna, and not Vasushena (his name of birth).

So, my question is, why was Karna called with such a name if he still did not donate his armor? Does the donation of his armour happen in Adi Parva? It is not a question of his other names, it is a question about why it is so called if it received the name "Vaikartana Karna" after the donation of its armor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how many different names of Karna are mentioned in Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24067/how-many-different-names-of-karna-are-mentioned-in-mahabharata)

Comment: **Vaikartana: the son of Vikartana (Surya)**...this is one more meaning...and that's why it's used in Adi parva...In Adi parva the summary of Mahabharata was already narrated thenn Janmejya asked it in detail that means thr story of donating armour was covered....also the story is narrated to Janmejya when Karna was already dead...and the famous name can be used without following chronological order...one more such example is Ravana...this name was given by Shiva but in the Ramayana u can find this name even before he met Shiva as this was the most famous name...

Comment: This is not a duplicate question!!